# Facebook Login response does not have email and public profile data

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have simple login button:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="234" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false" data-scope="public_profile,email" data-onlogin="system.onFacebookAuth()"></div>
```

And simple callback:

```
system.onFacebookAuth = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I'm trying to sign in and:

```
{…}
authResponse: {…}
accessToken: "..."
expiresIn: 3917
reauthorize_required_in: 7775999
signedRequest: "..."
userID: "90204760053877350"
<prototype>: Object { … }
status: "connected"
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

That's all. There is no email, not even public profile data such as user name. Can you explain me what's wrong please?

Comment: see my answer. btw, you REALLY need to be careful with access tokens. putting them online is like leaving your house key in front of your house for everyone to take when you leave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the API in your code. `FB.getLoginStatus` just checks if the user authorized your App. This would be an API call:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email,name'}, (response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Facebook documentation is very unclear as for me.